What " binary selection" exists in BM25?
I was reading Chapter 14 Question Answering, Information Retrieval, and RAG of Jurafsky's book specifically the section on document scoring where Okapi BM25 was brought up. I understood the prior calculation and explanation of tf-idf but I don't get this phrase highlighted in magenta.

... just a binary selection of terms in the query (plus idf).


Where is the binary selection? What 2 things are choosing from?
Wouldn't k=0 not give us 1 for the weighted tf?
Why does he say plus idf while the



$\texttt{BM25}$ (Best Matching 25), is a (probabilistic) ranking function widely used in information retrieval. It assigns scores to documents based on their relevance to a query, considering factors such as term frequency (TF), inverse document frequency (IDF), and document length normalisation. Here I will discuss the concept of binary selection within $\texttt{BM25}$, its implications, and its relation to preprocessing and post-retrieval steps, while addressing the OP's specific questions.
Definition of $\texttt{BM25}$
The $\texttt{BM25}$ score of a document $D$ for a query $Q$ is calculated as:
$$
\texttt{$\texttt{BM25}$}(D, Q) = \sum_{t \in Q} \texttt{IDF}(t) \cdot \frac{f(t, D) \cdot (k_1 + 1)}{f(t, D) + k_1 \cdot \left(1 - b + b \cdot \frac{|D|}{\texttt{avgDL}}\right)}
$$
Where:

$f(t, D)$: Frequency of term $t$ in document $D$.
$|D|$: Length of the document.
$\texttt{avgDL}$: Average document length in the corpus.
$k_1$ and $b$: Tuning parameters, where $k_1$ controls term frequency saturation, and $b$ adjusts the effect of document length normalisation.
$\texttt{IDF}(t)$: Inverse document frequency, defined as:

$$
\texttt{IDF}(t) = \log \frac{N - n(t) + 0.5}{n(t) + 0.5}
$$
Here:

$N$: Total number of documents in the corpus.
$n(t)$: Number of documents containing the term $t$.

The additive 0.5 in IDF smooths extreme cases where $n(t)$ is very small or large, preventing division by zero or overemphasis of rare terms.
Some implementations of $\texttt{BM25}$ (such as the one quoted in the OP) use a logarithmic variant of the term frequency weighting component, where the weighted term frequency is transformed as
$$
\log\left(1 + \frac{f(t, D)}{k_1 \cdot \left(1 - b + b \cdot \frac{|D|}{\texttt{avgDL}}\right)}\right)
$$
This logarithmic transformation provides additional smoothing, reducing the dominance of terms with very high frequencies. While this variant can be useful in tasks where repeated terms contribute diminishing returns to relevance, the standard $\texttt{BM25}$ formula without the logarithmic adjustment is more commonly used in production systems, such as Lucene. Both approaches are valid, and the choice depends on the specific requirements of the retrieval task.
Addressing the OP’s Questions

1. Where is the binary selection? What 2 things are being chosen from?


Binary selection in $\texttt{BM25}$ is implicit in its formula:

Terms present in a document contribute to the score, as $f(t, D) > 0$.
Terms absent in a document do not contribute, as $f(t, D) = 0$ nullifies their impact.



Thus, the “two things” being chosen from are whether a term contributes to the score or is ignored entirely.

2. Wouldn't $k_1 = 0$ not give us 1 for the weighted TF?


If $k_1 = 0$, the term frequency weight simplifies to 1:

$$
\frac{f(t, D) \cdot (k_1 + 1)}{f(t, D) + k_1 \cdot \left(1 - b + b \cdot \frac{|D|}{\texttt{avgDL}}\right)} = 1.
$$
This is because:

The numerator becomes $f(t, D) \cdot (0 + 1) = f(t, D)$.
The denominator becomes $f(t, D)$ as $k_1 = 0$ eliminates the additional length normalisation term.

Effectively, $k_1 = 0$ removes the influence of term frequency, treating all terms as binary (either present or absent).

3. Why does he say “plus idf”?


I think the phrase emphasises the integration of IDF into $\texttt{BM25}$. While $\texttt{BM25}$ does not literally “add” IDF, this multiplier enhances the contribution of rare terms and diminishes the effect of common terms, complementing term frequency.

Binary Selection in $\texttt{BM25}$
1. Term Presence or Absence
$\texttt{BM25}$ inherently incorporates binary selection by ignoring terms not present in a document. Due to its multiplicative structure, if $f(t, D) = 0$, the term $t$ contributes nothing to the score. This reflects $\texttt{BM25}$'s focus on selectively scoring documents based on query terms present in the document.
2. Query Expansion and Preprocessing
Binary selection can occur during preprocessing or query expansion, where terms are explicitly included or excluded based on specific rules:

Stopword Removal: Common words like "the" or "is" are removed to reduce noise.
Stemming and Lemmatisation: Related terms (eg., "run" and "running") are normalised to a common root to improve recall, though this may sacrifice some precision in term distinction.
Custom Term Selection: In domain-specific contexts, binary rules can exclude irrelevant terms or prioritise significant ones.

These preprocessing steps indirectly affect $\texttt{BM25}$ scores by modifying the term representation.
3. Thresholding for Relevance
Binary selection is also applied in post-retrieval filtering, where a threshold is set on $\texttt{BM25}$ scores. For example:

Documents with scores below a certain threshold may be excluded.
Threshold values should align with the retrieval task and corpus properties. For instance, in a large corpus, a score threshold of 10 might filter low-relevance documents effectively.

While not part of $\texttt{BM25}$ itself, this thresholding step introduces a binary decision layer in the retrieval pipeline.
References

Jurafsky, D., & Martin, J. H. (2023). Speech and Language Processing (3rd Edition). Chapter 14. Stanford University.
Robertson, S., & Zaragoza, H. (2009). The probabilistic relevance framework: $\texttt{BM25}$ and beyond. Foundations and Trends® in Information Retrieval, 3(4), 333-389.


Thank you for the long answer and mentioning production practices and also Lucene. I wouldn't have known about them otherwise.
